# How to append custom calendar in CRON URI?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

calendar = new org.quartz.calendar();
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI&customCalendar"+calendar).to("activemq:Totally.Rocks")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to use an instance in your route, you have to declare it in the Camel Registry. So you should like it has been here [1]

With the @bindToRegistry annotation, you'll add your instance to the registry and you'll be able to reference it in your route through the '#' symbol.

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI&customCalendar=#calendar").to("activemq:Totally.Rocks")
```

where calendar is the name you're declaring in your @bindToRegistry annotation.

Please, be aware that the example linked here is coming from Camel 3.

Maybe have a look at Registry documentation [2] too

[1] https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quartz/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/quartz/QuartzCustomCalendarFireTest.java

[2] https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/registry.html

Comment: Mine is Camel 2.24, is any solution for that?

Comment: You can do in this way: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/components/camel-quartz2/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/quartz2/QuartzCustomCalendarFireTest.java

Comment: How to customize my own calendar by using org.quartz.calendar?

Comment: In the jndi.bind("calendar", cal) cal could be of type org.quartz.calendar

Comment: Exception while adding the routes to camel contextorg.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.
Resgistry in my context is not Jndiregistry?